# Rounded Button color is not getting change in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a rounded button in Android studio, so for a rounded button, I added a new XML file and have used that file as a background for the button. The background color by default is purple I want to make it white. I made changes in XML (the color is now set to white), but still, when I check it in design it still looks purple.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="1.5dp" />
<corners android:radius="25dp"/>
</shape>

 Button Code:
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded2"
    android:backgroundTint="#F4F3F3"
    android:text="Message"
    android:textColor="#090808"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Comment: use android:drawableTint="@color/white" or android:tint="@color/section_arrowup_color"

Comment: both are not working sir

Answer (score 1):

use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton tag instead of Button in your xml file.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="123dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded2"
android:text="Message"
android:textColor="#090808"
android:textSize="16sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Comment: yes, it works now, but now the button is not in rounded format anymore. I have made separate XML to make the button round. and have used that XML as the background of the button. but the button is not inn rounded anymore

Comment: @zulkefalmohammadzai then just remove android:backgroundTint="#F4F3F3"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MaterialButton` instead of `Button`

Using `MaterialButton` you can add stroke, background color using attributes of `MaterialButton` instead of creating separate `drawable` file.

For Button Stroke:

```
app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
app:strokeColor="@color/white"
```

For Button Radius:

```
app:cornerRadius="25dp"
```

For Button Background:

```
app:backgroundTint="#F4F3F3"
```

MaterialButton Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#F4F3F3"
        app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:cornerRadius="25dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textColor="#090808"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

for **XML** try below line and see if its working fine or not .

```
   android:drawableTint="@color/white"    
   android:tint="@color/section_arrowup_color"
```

for kotlin try below code.

```
    DrawableCompat.setTint(arrowSign.getDrawable(),
    ContextCompat.getColor(arrowSign.getContext(), R.color.orange));

    DrawableCompat.setTint(button.getBackground(),
    ContextCompat.getColor(button.getContext(), R.color.darkBlack));
```